# React Warning, setState(...) in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this warning with the setState in the functin below, can anone tell me how I need to structure my code to get rid of it?

**warning.js:46 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the FileInput component.**

```
    componentDidMount: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.initUploader();

    this.uploader.init();

    EVENTS.forEach(function (event) {
        var handler = self.props['on' + event];
        if (typeof handler === 'function') {
            self.uploader.bind(event, handler);
        }
    });


   this.uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
        var objResponse = JSON.parse(res.response);
        console.log(objResponse.reference);
        self.props.getFileRef(objResponse.reference);


        var stateFiles = self.state.files;
        _.map(stateFiles, function (val, key) {
            if (val.id === file.id) {
                val.uploaded = true;
                stateFiles[key] = val;
            }
        });
        // setState causing warning
        self.setState({ files: stateFiles }, function () {
            self.removeFile(file.id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where `self` is defined?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, updated post

Answer (score 2):

The `FileUploaded` event handler is invoking `setState` using a closure `self` reference. This causes leaks where the component has been unmounted and then the `FileUploaded` event triggers and setState is invoked on an unmounted component. You can read more about this in this article which is somewhat related - https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html.

Now how to fix this depends on if your `uploader` object allows for unbinding the event handler. If it allows, then you can do this -

1. Define the `FileUploaded` handler code as a named function (instead of anonymous). You need to do this to be able to unbind it later.
2. Change the code in `componentDidMount` to bind the named function as the `FileUploaded` event handler.
3. Add a `componentWillUnmount` event handler to your component and call the unbind mechanism of `uploader`, passing it the named handler reference.

This way, when the component gets unmounted, the corresponding handler will also be removed and this warning will no longer be reported.

PS: You should remove (unbind) *all* handlers you are registering in your code above, otherwise you will be leaking references all over the place and more importantly, will be left with a whole bulk of orphaned event handlers.

==UPDATE==

Per your Fiddle, you can -

1. Declare these new methods in your component -

   ```
   registerHandler: function(uploader, event, handler){
       this.handlers = this.handlers || [];
     this.handlers.push({e: event, h: handler});
     uploader.bind(event, handler);
   },

   unregisterAllHandlers : function(uploader){
       for (var i = 0; i < this.handlers.length; i++){
           var handler = this.handlers[i],
           e = handler.e,
           h = handler.h;
           // REPLACE with the actual event unbinding method
           // of uploader.
           uploader.unbind(e, h);
           delete this.handlers[i];
       }
   },

   componentWillUnmount: function(){
       this.unregisterAllHandlers(this.uploader);
   }
   ```
2. Use `registerHandler` in all the places where you are invoking `uploader.bind` -

   `self.registerHandler(self.uploader, event, handler);`

   OR

   `this.registerHandler(this.uploader,'FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
           if (_.get(self.props, 'multi_selection') === false) {...});`

This is a very crude implementation, basically we are storing all event handler references in an array and then during unmount, removing them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have any code examples on how I would do that?

Comment: The linked article has good code samples. If you can create a jsfiddle, I can modify it with the suggested approach.

Comment: I have a fiddle here, I'm already binding in componentDidMount, 

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/43248/